# How to check deleted question

Tags: discussion, moderation

I had a question from my account deleted, was it by my or by a moderator?

Answer (score 6):

You currently have 5 out of 11 questions deleted.

- Of the 5, 4 were closed by the community and one was closed by a moderator.
- Of the 5, you deleted one, 3 were deleted automatically and the last one was deleted by a community user and a moderator.
- Deleted by you

  - https://serverfault.com/questions/378438/team-viewer-installation-issue-after-trial-version-expire
- Deleted automatically

  - https://serverfault.com/questions/404983/lcd-display-issue
  - https://serverfault.com/questions/382187/sharing-a-folder-on-ubuntu-11-10
  - https://serverfault.com/questions/373916/skype-is-not-connecting
- Deleted by community + moderator

  - https://serverfault.com/questions/434795/get-email-backups-of-any-mail-accounts

Answer (score 5):

You're referring to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/434795/get-email-backups-of-any-mail-accounts).  And you should be able to see who deleted it, and a reason (if they left one), as it's a post you made.

For what it's worth, it was deleted because it was

1. [Crossposted/reposted from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/483347/how-to-get-email-backups).
2. Very off topic.
3. An incredibly bad question with no value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a Moderator deleted Question.